# Search Using id and name from two different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I want to search product as per user inserted *keyword*.
Currently i am doing by explode user keyword and by using `SQL LIKE`.

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $psearch);//psearch = User keyword
$searchTermKeywords = array();
foreach ($keywords as $word) 
{
  $searchTermKeywords[] = "name  Like '%$word%'";
}
$qry_p = "SELECT * FROM product 
          where ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermKeywords)." 
          && status=1
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12";
```

but it will work only when product have contained named that user has entered.

---

This is My First Table ***"Product"***

[image]

And This is second one Named ***"Category"***

[image]

Now i wants to perform an action like if User Search for `Saree` So All Products who's category id is 1(*mean by saree*) Should be display.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Inner Join on your Product and category table using product.`category = category.id` and in select term add category.name as category_name. 
Also update your search condition with

`foreach ($keywords as $word) 
{
  $searchTermKeywords[] = "product.name  Like '%$word%' OR category_name  Like '%$word%'";
}`

Please try above code and update as per your search term fields.
Hope this will help you.